# Targeting multiple buttons on a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

new to Javascript here. My experience is more so in html/css.

I have multiple buttons on my page (class is homebuttonlink, homebuttonlink2, etc) and I need javascript to create a variable with the URL. My original code worked with just one button but when I tried to add a "homebutton2", neither of them work anymore. The way I see it, it should create both a homebutton and homebutton2 variable, listen to both of them and then make whichever one is clicked the target. Is someone willing to help me out?

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
    document.querySelectorAll('.homebuttonlink').forEach(element => {
          element.addEventListener('click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let target = event.currentTarget.href;
            console.log(target);

            transition_el.classList.add('is-active');

            setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.href = target;
            }, 500);

          });
        }
```

```html
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="page1/#one">BUTTON1</a>
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="page2/#two">BUTTON1</a>
```

UPDATE: I tried David Thomas's code, but I couldn't make it work. The end goal is a page transition and delay. I've updated my code above to reflect my complete code with the suggested code added.

Comment: And what HTML are you working with, because assuming the elements have the relevant class (and they're the first thing in the page with the classes) that looks like it should work.

Comment: I updated my post with a more complete look at my code and the suggested answer incorporated. Still not working unfortunately.

Comment: In what way is it "not working," because in a JS Fiddle demo (once the syntax is corrected (`"SyntaxError: missing ")" after argument list"`), and I comment out the lines looking for, and using, non-existent elements (`.transition`) as well as the preventing the new page being loaded) it seems to work: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o1k5wxrz/).

Comment: Turns out it was syntax error. I needed to use  });  }) } to close everything. It works as intended now. Thank you very much for your help. I did have one question though, why the "#one", "#two", etc?

Comment: I don't know the context for the question, I'm afraid; can you be more explicit about what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to loop through all the elements matching your selector. For example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.homebuttonlink').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let target = event.currentTarget.href;
        console.log(target);
    });
});
```

```html
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="/home.html#one">Home</a>
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="/home.html#two">A la casa</a>
```

Or you can use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), depending on what you prefer:

```js
const homebuttons = document.querySelectorAll('.homebuttonlink');

for (const element of homebuttons) {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let target = event.currentTarget.href;
        console.log(target);
    });
}
```

```html
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="/home.html#one">Home</a>
<a class="homebuttonlink" href="/home.html#two">A la casa</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I couldn't make it work. I updated my post with a more complete view of my code and your suggestion added. Maybe I typoed somewhere?

Comment: To answer your question from above, the link fragments (`#one` & `#two`) are just there so you can see that you're referencing different links. You don't actually need them for your code to work.